# Charpit PDE, rays parallel or perpendicular to boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

[image]

The rays are all possible curves $(x(\tau), y(\tau))$.
The derivation of the equations is clear and the condition of defining $p_0, q_0$ is $\frac{dx_0}{ds}\frac{dy_0}{d\tau} - \frac{dy_0}{ds}\frac{dx_0}{d\tau} \neq 0$. But:

1) Why is this condition equivalent to "rays not being parallel to $\Gamma$"?

2) What is a similar condition (and why does it hold) when we want the rays to be orthogonal to $\Gamma$?

Any help appreciated!